# write a shell script to collect log messages from two or more servers

Tags: shell-script, centos, logs

collect the log messages from the more servers using shellscript in centos.

I have already tired a small script to get the log message. but the problem is when i try to login it is not working. so I need the script where I can login with different servers and take the log messages using the script.

The script below is which i tired

```
#!/bin/sh 

echo Enter the count of the server that you need to check for the log messages
read countofserver
for (( c=1; c<=$countofserver; c++ ))
do
echo if you want to continue again press 1 or to quit press any number
read continue
if [ $continue -eq 1 ]
then
echo Enter the ip which you want to login
read loginip
ssh root@$loginip
echo Below are the log messages of the server $loginip
cat /var/log/messages
else
echo exit
fi
done
```

Comment: Please do not post graphical screenshots. Just copy and paste your code using markdown

Comment: Seems like this is a school project. Use `scp` to collect the log messages from the different servers. Set up ssh based auth first and then use `scp`

Comment: "I can't login" doesn't tell much - a better way is "when I try to login...". The first thing to do is to verify you can login in the first place just from the shell. You're SSH:ing in as `root`, and commonly `root` isn't allowed to SSH in for security reasons. In some Linux distributions `root` is entirely disabled by default for the same reason. The way to do this is 1) get the basic thing working on command line 2) when working put the commands in script 3) test the script 4) if working add embellishments like helpful messages or user input.

Comment: how can i do it through script for setting up the ssh based auth @GMaster

Comment: SCP works over SSH, so if you're able to login with SSH your'e able to copy with SCP. See [Wikipedia SCP page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy_protocol) and [man scp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html),

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elk-stack

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I don't think you intended that here :-)

Comment: I'm not a fan of such "on the knee" "solutions". :-)

Comment: AH... :-D OK, I need coffee...

Comment: can you please refer any sites for rsyslog method @roaima

Comment: @zara `https://rsyslog.com` would be a good starting point for finding how to forward messages to a central server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're using `rsyslog` on your unspecified version of CentOS.

The most straightforward solution to your problem is to use the feature set built in to every implementation of the `syslog` subsystem that allows it to send messages to a central server. There is then no need to have to copy the logs around using any form of script - it just happens automatically.

One such recipe can be found for `rsyslog`:

- [Sending messages to a remote server](https://www.rsyslog.com/sending-messages-to-a-remote-syslog-server/)
- [Receiving messages from remote servers](https://www.rsyslog.com/receiving-messages-from-a-remote-system/)

Here is a summary of the instructions from that documentation

1. Sending messages

   Add this line to a suitably named file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` - for example if you are sending to a machine called `mushroom` with IP address `192.168.10.1` you might call it `send_to_mushroom.conf`:

   ```
   # Everything to "mushroom" via port 60514
   *.*  action(type="omfwd" target="192.168.10.1" port="60514" protocol="tcp"
           action.resumeRetryCount="100"
           queue.type="linkedList" queue.size="10000")
   ```

   Change the initial `*.*` to this subset of messages if you want just events written to `/var/log/messages`:

   ```
   *.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;auth,authpriv.none;cron,daemon.none;mail.none
   ```
2. Receiving messages

   Uncomment these lines, or add them to a configuration file such as  `/etc/rsyslog.d/from_remotes`:

   ```
   module(load="imtcp")
   input(type="imtcp" port="60514")
   ```

Now restart both the client and server instances of `rsyslogd` and watch the messages roll in. (Remember to allow tcp/50514 through any intermediate firewalls.)

Answer (score 0):

Here, `ssh root@$loginip` will start an interactive secure shell and wait it to exit. Afterward, `cat /var/log/messages` is executed locally.

You can type instead :

```
echo Below are the log messages of the server $loginip
ssh root@$loginip cat /var/log/messages
```

Here, `cat /var/log/messages` is executed remotely.

(`scp`can also be used to copy files)

Note that ssh will ask you everytime the password. You could avoid it using ssh keys and a key-agent.

Login as root is not recommanded. On a Debian, the `/var/log/messages` can be read by any member of the adm group. You should use a normal user inside this group. (On other distribution, verify `ls -l /var/log/messages`).

If you want to quit, use `exit`, not `echo exit` (which just print exit).

Your script doesn't initialise `$loginip`. You may replace your for loop by `while read loginip;do`

Answer (score 0):

I tired this it was running good. It store the log messages separtely in each folder which is named with their ipaddresses.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Enter the count of the server that you need to check for the log messages
read countofserver
for (( c=1; c<=$countofserver; c++ ))
do
echo Enter the ip which you want to login
read loginip
mkdir /root/logmessages/$loginip -p
scp root@$loginip:/var/log/messages /root/logmessages/$loginip/
done
```